# Will my data be erased when I upgrade from saucy salamander to Trusty Tahr?

Tags: upgrade

I want to upgrade but I´m afraid that all my data will be erased, and I cant make a data backup because I don´t have the needed hardware.

Comment: "and I cant make a data backup because I don´t have the needed hardware." Nobody is forcing you to upgrade so fix that 1st. You can always store your important files online (filedrive or googledrive)

Comment: More than that, you should back up your user data even if you're not planning on an upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

You should always backup your files. If you don't backup them, you don't value them and sooner or later you *will* lose them.

But no, they won't be erased *if everything goes well* during the upgrade.
None of your installed applications or of your settings should be lost either - you'll just get newer versions of your programs. Before the upgrade procedure removes any package which it thinks you don't need anymore it will ask whether it should.

Afterwards you'll pretty much have the same system as before, with small changes and newer versions of most software.

Comment: And what will happen with my apps? like for example I use peppermint instead of flash player because the reasons anyone that uses Ubunutu knows... I like to see series and other all the time in my pc, will pepperment still work on the upgrade?

Comment: @user282599: what is peppermint and what do we all know? Flash and Silverlight works well on Ubuntu. If you're talking about Peppermint OS, this is not the right site.

Comment: @Marc: I don't know what strange kind of apps you are talking about, but any normal packages installed with Ubuntu Software Center/apt-get/aptitude/etc packager manager will stay when you do an upgrade. What you describe sounds like reinstalling while keeping /etc and /home.

Comment: @Nobody: I stand corrected. I've done many more re-installs than upgrades and I misspoke.